# Python says: "IndexError: string index out of range."

Tags: python, python-3.3

I am making some practice code for a game similar to the board game, MasterMind-- and It keeps coming out with this error, and I can't figure out why it's doin it. Here's the code:

```
def Guess_Almost (Guess, Answer):
    a = ''.join([str(v) for v in Answer])
    g = str(Guess)
    n = 0
    am = 0
    while n < 5:
        if g[n] == a[0]:
            am = am + 1
        if g[n] == a[2]:
            am = am + 1
        if g[n] == a[3]:
            am = am + 1
        if g[n] == a[3]:
            am = am + 1
        n = n + 1
    return(am)
```

Okay, the Guess is specified to be 4 integers, and the Answer is a list containing 4 numbers. They both have the same 'len' after the code, so i don't have a clue.

The point of this code is to turn the Answer into a string of 4 numbers, and see if any of those numbers match thoise of the guess, and return how many total matches there are.

Comment: `Answer` ? in your call

Comment: 1) In what line does this occur? 2) Are the indexes `0233` intended or did you mean `0123`?

Comment: Your variable names are way too short. It's also not possible to answer this without knowing what the value of `Guess` is. Also, I've no idea what you mean by "making a code box", and yet it seems like the subquestion isn't appropriate for SO. (Neither are subquestions in and of themselves.)

Comment: If you are going to use this approach, make sure you are checking the length of the strings.  In other words, if len(g) >= 5 and len(a) >=5: then ....  I am guessing that is the cause of your index out of range errors.

Comment: @millimoose: I'm guessing that by "code box" he meant formatting the code for StackOverflow (which has since been done in edits) so it's not really a subquestion.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Good catch. (Nonetheless that's what the editing help and maaaybe meta is for.)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps

```
def Guess_Almost (Guess, Answer):

   a = ''.join([str(v) for v in Answer])
   g = str(Guess)
   n = 0
   am = 0
   if len(g) >= 5 and len(a) >=4:
     while n < 5:
        if g[n] == a[0]:
           am = am + 1
        if g[n] == a[2]:
           am = am + 1
        if g[n] == a[3]:
            am = am + 1
        if g[n] == a[3]:
          am = am + 1
         n = n + 1
  return(am)
```